# Why pow() function working correctly, only after saving it to a variable?

Tags: c, variables, undefined-behavior, pow, math.h

I were asked to c-program to accept two variables and print the answer when second variable is raised to the power of first variable. So I coded,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 
int x,y;

int main()
{
scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
printf("%d",pow(x,y));
}
```

It should be working right? But it doesn't! So I done

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 
int x,y;

int main()
{
scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
int u=pow(x,y);
printf("%d",u);
}
```

Then it worked. i.e for the inputs like **x=10 y=3**

> the output for the first snippet, was **11829309**
> something I don't remember.

> But the second one results correctly as **1000**.

Please, tell why this happened?

Comment: Typo: `printf("%d", pow(x,y));` ==> `printf("%f\n", pow(x,y));` Unlike the type conversion in `int u=pow(x,y);` the variadic functions like `printf` must be given the correct type.

Comment: Because `pow` return a `double` and this is converted if you assign to `int` while it is not if you pass it to a variadic function.

Comment: or, for this simple test case (normally prefer other options), `printf("%d\n", (int)pow(x, y));`

Comment: Aside, with integer values you would be advised to do `(int)round(pow(x, y))`

Comment: Unrelated: no reason for `x` and `y` to be global variables. Define them inside `main()` instead (as local variables).

Answer (score 0):

`pow` returns a **double**, therefore causing undefined behavior because you pass it to a format string expecting an **int**, since **typeof(pow(int,int)) == double.**

Try

```
printf("%lf\n", pow(3,5));
```

or use an explicit cast, like

```
printf("%d\n", (int)pow(3,5));
```

You're trying to print that double value with the %d conversion specifier:
`printf("%d",pow(x,y));`

which expects an int value, but provides a double.

Comment: @pmg I just wanted to state a general problem. Doesn't matter if you divide it and save as a float or save as a double while using pow, the explicit cast is required. But thanks, i've edited it.